# Problem using C++ Eigen norm() function on a Vector of doubles

Tags: c++, eigen

I have the following:

```
Eigen::Vector3d X, Y, Z;  
Z = (X-Y).norm();
```

What is the Eigen equivalent of Matlab's norm() that can work on a vector of doubles?

The error I get is at the '=' ... it says:
" no operator "=" matches these operands ... operand types are Eigen::Vector3d = double "

Comment: What are you expecting from your code? Norm is a number, `Z` is a vector.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov ah yes, youre right. I should use .normalize() instead.

Comment: You mean `Z = (X-Y).normalized();`? (not the same as `.normalize()`)